# Does MySQL Query Caching work across sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session, query-cache

I am developing a reporting web application using PHP/MySQL, and I believe every call to MySQL from PHP is a new session. The MySQL documentation that I read says that the query caching feature is only available in that session.

I tried Googling, but didn't get an answer to this, but is it possible to make query caching available across sessions, perhaps even in the next day? Alternatively, would there be any other way to cache my queries without writing the output to some physical table?

Comment: "The MySQL query cache is a global one shared among the sessions. It caches the select query along with the result set, which enables the identical selects to execute faster as the data fetches from the in memory. " - https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/02/the-mysql-query-cache-how-it-works-and-workload-impacts-both-good-and-bad/ Basic premise of your question is based on wrong assumption.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I had read that link as well. I guess I got confused due to the word, "among". So I wasn't sure whether it works only in the current session or if closed and re-opened as well.